# Clearing laravel 4.2 class file cache

Tags: php, apache, laravel, caching, laravel-4

I'm working with laravel 4.2 and i created a model `model_test.php`, it kept working until i added a function `scopeTest` and tried to call it, then i had the error **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::test()**.
i started debugging and it turned out that the file is kinda cached. here is some tests i did:

- when i'm not calling the function test() everything looks fine as
  expected.
- when i rename, empty or even delete the file `model_test.php`
  everything still working but it shouldn't because i'm using the file
  with all functions inside it.

I ran laravel and composer commands to clear the cache but still not working.

That happened to me twice. Maybe it's apache cache!

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in Composer, it was loading a different file (a copy I made as a backup ) instead of the original, I changed it manually in the file `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.
the class name was pointing to the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

`scope`-functions are magic in Laravel. You can read about how here: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Thx but i'm sure the problem is not scope-functions because it's working on local .